# how to check values in list without repeating checked elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i'm doing a game, The goal of the game is to guess a hidden sequence of number randomly generated by the computer.

The scoring role are:

1. For every right guess WITH right position -i would add 1 to black (start is 0)
2. For every right guess BUT NOT in right position -i would add 1 to white (start is 0)

note* every guess should only be tallied once; either +1 black, +1 white, or none at all. it can't be +1 black and +1 white at the same time for 1 guess (which is my current problem)

The problem is when i try to compute for the score (i'll give an example to make it easier)

```
this is the example (not the code, but someone indented it)
the hidden sequence is [4, 1, 4, 9]

entered sequence of guess: 1111
score: [1, 3] #[black, white]
expected score: [1, 0] #+1 on black cause of 2nd number 2 being in right position; +0 on white because there is only one 1 in the hidden sequence, and that one is in right position already

entered sequence of guess: 4141
score: [3, 1]
expected score: [3, 0] #+3 on black cause 414 are in the right sequence; +0 on white because there is only one 1 in the hidden sequence, and that one is in right position already

entered sequence of guess: 1414
score: [0, 4]
expected score: [0, 3] #+3 on white because there are two 4's and one 1 in the sequence; +0 on black because there are no correct numbers in right position
```

the one below is the what i currently have and the needed code to understand and fix the problem

```
import random

highest = 9
lowest = 1
num1 = random.randint(lowest, highest)
num2 = random.randint(lowest, highest)
num3 = random.randint(lowest, highest)
num4 = random.randint(lowest, highest)
hidden = [num1, num2, num3, num4]

#starting from this part, everything is nested in a while loop to let me guess until a certain amount of number
#if i have exceeded the number of attempts allowed, or if i have guessed the right sequence; the loop will end
guess = int(input("enter guess here: "))
a = guess // 1000
b = guess // 100 % 10
c = guess // 10 % 10
d = guess % 10
P1guess = [a, b, c, d]

white = 0
black = 0

checkctr = 0
x = 0
#this loop right here is my problem
while checkctr < 4:
    if P1guess[x] == hidden[x]:
        black += 1
    elif P1guess[x] in hidden:
        white += 1
    x += 1
        checkctr += 1

print("black: " + str(black))
print("white: " + str(white))
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Please cut this down to a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain the problem more clearly.

Comment: I assume the scoring examples are incorrect and you want to fix them? Could you put the desired results alongside the current ones?

Comment: serbitar: the problem is once a guess and a hidden value matched, the program will still check other guesses if it still matches with the hidden value that has already been satisfied

jonrharpe: sorry, had to give examples cause i'm not very good at explaining; edited some stuffs in hope of making it more understandable

vilmar: edited and added the desired/expected results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you looking at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_%28board_game%29

```
white = 0
black = 0
hidden = [4, 1, 4, 9]
P1guess = [1, 1, 1, 4]
import copy
non_exact_hidden = copy.copy(hidden)
non_exact_match = copy.copy(P1guess)
checkctr = 0
x = 0
while checkctr < 4:
    if P1guess[x] == hidden[x]:
        black += 1
        # remove from the list that we consider non exact match
        non_exact_hidden.remove(hidden[x])
        non_exact_match.remove(hidden[x])
    x += 1
    checkctr += 1

# go over non exact matches and score them appropriately 
for guess in non_exact_match:
    if guess in non_exact_hidden:
        white += 1
```

this will give you 1, 1

which i assume is closer to what you expect right?
it's not too elegant though...

Comment: the next problem arises as i continue to play the game: program experiences error when an element from list has been removed and then typed again...example: hidden = [4, 1, 4, 9], 1st P1guess = [1, 1, 1, 1], score = [1, 0],, 2nd P1guess =[1, 1, 1, 1], ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Comment: you have to copy into non_exact_hidden and non_exact_match on every outer loop run, before each match non_exact_hidden have to equal hidden.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the problem correctly, you want to score the number only once. The best way to solve it, assuming the generated list and the guess are of the same length, is to iterate through the generated list:

```
for i, val in enumerate(hidden):
    if hidden[i] == P1guess[i]:
        black += 1
    #I assume we grade the number only once
    elif val in P1guess:
        white += 1
```

You need to clarify your scoring rules a bit. Considering the generated sequence is [4, 1, 1, 1] and your guess is [1, 9, 9, 9], it will give you the score of [0, 3]. If you want it to be [0, 1] in this case, then the code needs to be updated.

Comment: in your example, i was expecting the score to be [0, 1] ..thanks for making my problem easier to understand for the others